# Js overriding hyperlink in source code (Cubicle Template by W3Layouts)

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, tags

I have been trying to crack this one out, whenever I click the link in the << li >> tag, it responds nothing.

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse navbar-right collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right cross-effect" id="cross-effect">

<li><a class="cross-effect" href="#features">ES Values</a></li>
<li><a class="cross-effect" href="#about">About ES</a></li>
<li><a class="cross-effect" href="#testimonial">ES Testimonials</a></li>
<li><a class="cross-effect" href="#stats">ES Stats</a></li>
<li><a class="cross-effect" href="http://www.google.com">ES Gallery</a></li>
<li><a class="cross-effect" href="/groups.html" target="_self">ES Groups</a></li>
<li><a class="cross-effect" href="/updates.html" target="_self">ES Updates</a></li>
<li><a class="cross-effect" href="/contact.html" target="_self">Contact ES</a></li>
                </ul>
```

please help me out. it's from the cubicle template from w3layouts

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle, because it is very difficult to notice what is going wrong?

Comment: hi @TeutaKoraqi, appreciate ur reply, here is the temporary link to the file
http://myes4ucom.ipage.com/esfull/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem is because those that you are clicking, they do not lead to this section page that you divided by id, the lead to another page, and this animation that you added for smooth scroll, is firing even on those links that lead to another page, so add a class to those lists that have id, for example, give class test and change your code to this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".scroll, .navbar li.test a, .footer li a").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1000);
    });
   });
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right cross-effect" id="cross-effect">
    <li class="test"><a class="cross-effect" href="#features">ES Values</a></li>
 <li  class="test"><a class="cross-effect" href="#about">About ES</a></li>
 <li  class="test"><a class="cross-effect" href="#testimonial">ES Testimonials</a></li>
  <li  class="test"><a class="cross-effect" href="#stats">ES Stats</a></li>
    <li><a class="cross-effect" href="http://www.google.com">ES Gallery</a></li>
 <li><a class="cross-effect" href="/groups.html" target="_self">ES Groups</a></li>
 <li><a class="cross-effect" href="/updates.html" target="_self">ES Updates</a></li>
 <li><a class="cross-effect" href="contact.html" target="_blank" style="
    pointer-events: all;
">Contact ES</a></li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: A little advice: when anything doesn't seem to work properly, check out your console! It is very helpful, because you can see if an error occur. This doesn't happen every time, but in many cases yes! :)

Comment: Thanks @teutakoraqi but the [[ jQuery(document).ready(function($)... ]] is to be added to what document? im really sorry.. kinda newbie here.

Comment: I added the Jquery code to jquery.min.js , the hyperlink works but the rest of the animation gone.. cant even click the menu button for mobile size

Comment: No, you should't add the code to jquery.min.js! Leave it where it is, just, as I described in the code above, just give the same class to those list that lead to an id. When you do that, put those changes in you website online, so I can see if you did the right thing!

Comment: i have amend the code according what you gave, still not working. check and see http://myes4ucom.ipage.com/esfull/index.html hope you will help. thanks a lot.

Comment: No, you did not add the class to list as I said, it is the same like before